# The telegram bot webhook gets lost after each command call

Tags: php, laravel, telegram, php-telegram-bot, telegram-webhook

I'm using nutgram (https://nutgram.dev/docs) to call telegram bot methods.

[posman response](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivat0.png)

```
$this->bot->sendMessage( text: $description, chat_id: $group_id);
```

After calling each command, the webhook is lost, and Telegram cannot send me a response from the bot.

Comment: You should probably check on the status of your webhook, and see what the last error reported was. https://core.telegram.org/bots/api#getwebhookinfo

Comment: Thanks for the answer. Yes, I tried to make a getWebhookInfo request, immediately after each action with the bot the webhook url disappears https://i.stack.imgur.com/ivat0.png

Comment: Was hoping any of the error properties in there would be filled, but that seems not the case. // Such webhooks often automatically "unsubscribe", if your endpoint does not respond with status code 200 OK in a timely enough manner, so maybe check on that end, see if you got any 500 errors or similar logged for your endpoint URL.